# Cassandra table shows in the keyspaces but gives an error when performing any operation saying Table Doesn't exist

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax

I have table which I can see in the keyspaces, but when I try querying it gives error saying table doesn't exist. Similarly it won't even allow to drop the table. When I try to create similar table it gives an error saying Clustering column limit exceeded error.

Has anyone faced such issue? Help in resolve is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the DDL of the table you're trying to create? Maybe also a DESC KEYSPACE for the one you're trying to query?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on DataStax Astra. Solved by putting table name within double-quotes.

```sql
SELECT * FROM [YOUR-KEYSPACE-NAME]."[YOUR-TABLE-NAME]" LIMIT 10;
```